# Comma-Separated List of Media Queries Not Working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am coding a site with AngularJS and SCSS. I am in the mobile-phase of development and I quickly discovered (for this project) that I needed a way to target multiple breakpoints using a `@media` query. So I found via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668301/is-it-possible-to-nest-media-queries-within-media-queries) and [this CSS Tricks Post](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) as well as multiple other answers on SO. Then I implemented the solutions I found into a test-case, see snippet below for the test.

```css
main {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
        background-color: red
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        background-color: lightcoral
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px), (max-width: 992px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px),
    (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        background-color: lightblue;
        // Reset the min-height here, because we no longer have the sticky search bar.
        min-height: 450px;
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <h2>Some Descriptive information</h2>

    <div>Content</div>
</main>
```

But I haven't been able to get it to work. What I am trying to do, ultimately, is have styles that are applied when the user is in landscape on a tablet, or phone. However, I don't know if I am doing it right, or using the `or` operator correctly.

It plain doesn't work, well, the first statement (for example: `(max-width: 992px)`) works, but the second one doesn't evaluate to true. According to Mozilla:

> Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator or when used in media queries. When using a comma-separated list of media queries, if any of the media queries returns true, the styles or style sheets get applied. Each media query in a comma-separated list is treated as an individual query, and any operator applied to one media query does not affect the others. --- [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Logical_operators)

Even if I break the code into two separate media queries:

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
     background-color: lightgreen;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) and (orientation: landscape) {
     background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

It still doesn't work. So I don't know if I am targeting the wrong width (when in landscape) or what I am doing wrong. Can any other Front-End developers out there tell me why my comma seperated media queries aren't working?

**EDIT:** Here is the native SCSS code:

```css
main {
    background-color: $mono-90;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')) {
        // Reset the min-height here, because we no longer have the sticky search bar.
        min-height: 450px;
    }

    @media
    (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg')),
    (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg')) and (orientation: landscape){
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    @media
    (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')),
    (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')) and (orientation: landscape){
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    @media
    (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'sm')),
    (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'sm')) and (orientation: landscape){
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Per the recommendation of @Godwin, I simplified my `@media` queries to this:

```css
main {
    background-color: $mono-90;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')) {
        // Reset the min-height here, because we no longer have the sticky search bar.
        min-height: 450px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg')) {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')) {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'sm')) {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work on iPad Landscape (1024x768). I *don't* want it to show on Laptops, but *do* want it to show on iPads in Landscape position.

Comment: Logically this doesn't really make sense. You're essentially saying "If A is true OR if A and B are true then do something". The query will be true if the orientation is landscape or portrait, so why is it even a condition?

Comment: The thought is that I want to target specific elements depending on the orientation of the device. When I omit the orientation I am saying "these styles can be applied to either portrait or landscape, doesn't matter." But, as mentioned, there are _certain_ things that I only want to show on Landscape, but will already be hidden on Portrait.

Comment: What I'm saying is that, as far as I understand it, your statement equates to the same thing as `A || (A && B)` which can be simplified to `A`, it looks to me like there is an error in your logic. As it stands, a `lightgreen` `background-color` will be applied whenever the width is larger than the large breakpoint, regardless of the landscape.

Comment: I had that suspicion, very good point. I'll give that a shot and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried this but am still having an issue. I don't know if I need to use another media query for large screens (comma seperated) or not, but even with the above code, it doesn't work in iPad landscape. Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at this answer - it may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30104782/6256399

Answer (score 1):

> However, it doesn't work on iPad Landscape (1024x768). I don't want it to show on Laptops, but do want it to show on iPads in Landscape position.

I'm not sure what you're defining by **it** since you're not hiding anything in your examples so I'm gonna refer to:

> What I am trying to do, ultimately, is have styles that are applied when the user is in landscape on a tablet, or phone.

[Orientation on MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation) is defined as the following:

> This value does not correspond to actual device orientation.

It just indicates whether the viewport is in landscape (the display is wider than it is tall) or portrait (the display is taller than it is wide) mode.

You said your iPad in landscape has a resolution of 1024x768, so to target an iPad or a phone in landscape mode, you can set a media query targeting all devices having a maximum width of 1024px and being in landscape mode (the display is wider than it is tall):

```
main {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

You can check an example on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzRqWz).

If your viewport has a width greater than 1024px, the `main` element will be grey no matter what.

[image: Width greater than 1024px]

If you resize your browser window to have a viewport with a width equal or less than 1024px, and have a viewport considered in landscape (the display is wider than it is tall), for example an iPad in landscape mode (1024x768), the media query will trigger and apply a blue background:

[image: Width lesser than 1024px and landscape]

If you resize your browser window to still have a viewport with a with equal or less than 1024px but have an height greater than your width, the viewport is no longer considered to be in landscape mode but switch to portrait mode. At this time, the media query is no longer be triggered and we fallback to a grey element:

[image: Width lesser than 1024px and portrait]

So regarding your question, the example is a media query to apply styles to the user using a tablet or phone in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution .Hope this will work for you

```css
main {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
     
    @media (max-width: 992px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  main{
        background-color: red
  }
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  main{
        background-color: lightcoral
  }
    }
@media (max-width: 992px) and (orientation: landscape) {
   main{
        background-color: lightgreen;
   }
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
   main{
        background-color: lightblue;
        min-height: 450px;
   }
    }
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <h2>Some Descriptive information</h2>

    <div>Content</div>
</main>
```