# How should i use media querys correctly?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the content of my page wrapped inside a mycontainer div.
The stuff should be aligned in the center of the page using a big device and left when using a small device.

I defined a margin and the with of the container, which works flawless on the desktop. However the media query is not used on smartphones. Where is my mistake?

```
.mycontainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:50%;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 767) {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Edit: deleting `margin: 0 auto` in the media query does not change anything

Comment: Nesting isn't valid CSS, and I don't imagine nesting a media query like that inside of a selector is valid Sass either.

Comment: Are you using some preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@media ...` should be on the root level. You'll see `@media` queries used within selectors like you have it above, but that is only possible within CSS pre-processors like Sass. The correct way in plain CSS is as follows:

```
.mycontainer{
      margin: 0 auto;
      width:50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .mycontainer{
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure media queries can be nested within a selector like that even with Sass/Less.

Comment: Thanks mate!! It worked when i used styled-components. Does this mean styled-components do use a pre-processor?

Comment: @AlexanderNied it is possible, I learnt it a bit later too, wish I did sooner. This answer shows it in action https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103226/how-to-get-a-sass-nested-nested-media-query-to-work-with-the-use-of-the-media-qu

Comment: @nt369 Glad it helped. I believe so, sorry I don't have much exposure to styled components to answer that.

Comment: Whelp, I definitely learned something today-- verified that you are correct at https://www.sassmeister.com/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must have to mention proper size.

```
.mycontainer{
      margin: 0 auto;
      width:50%;

      @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
      }
}
```

Comment: it did not solved the problem

Comment: then you are using css not scss.
this type of code what you mention is scss.